# Problems using Qt with meson on Mac

Tags: c++, qt, meson-build

I stumbled across the build system meson ( http://mesonbuild.com/ ) which attracted me due to its simplicity and native Qt support.

However, when I followed the tutorial I got the error message

```
Build type: native build
Project name: qt5 demo
Native cpp compiler: c++ (clang 8.1.0)
Build machine cpu family: x86_64
Build machine cpu: x86_64
Found pkg-config: /usr/local/bin/pkg-config (0.29.2)
Dependency QtWidgets found: NO

Meson encountered an error in file meson.build, line 3, column 0:
Qt5 native dependency not found (checked pkg-config, qmake-qt5, and qmake)
```

which is weird because when I use Qt Creator I can create, compile, and execute Qt projects easily. I am using MacOS Sierra.
Can I somehow tell meson where qmake is located?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I fixed this issue by adding

```
export PATH="<path to qmake>":$PATH
```

to my .bash_profile file, where  is the path to the folder containing the qt binaries, such as qmake.